# Add a element in a non static object from a static method?

Tags: c#, nlog

I know how to use nlog to log my information in a file but now I would like to redirect my log to a ListView (C#) and do some actions. So I directed my log to a method as explained in the documentation nlog. It works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target name="msgbox" xsi:type="MethodCall" className="SomeNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly" methodName="LogMethod">
            <parameter layout="${level}" />
            <parameter layout="${message}" />
        </target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="msgbox" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Console.WriteLine works. It's not my problem.

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    using System;

    public class MyClass
    {
        public static void LogMethod(string level, string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("l: {0} m: {1}", level, message);
            // logListView.Items.Add(Message);
            // Do some other actions
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to add a line to my logListView (see commented line) but I can't because logListView is not static. How so? How do I proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to add a `static` member to MyClass, like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static ListView MyListView { get; set; }

    public static void LogMethod(string level, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("l: {0} m: {1}", level, message);
        var logListView = MyListView;
        if (logListView != null) {
            logListView.Items.Add(Message);
        }
        // Do some other actions
    }
}
```

You can set the value of `MyListView` from some other part of your application when it is available.

While this solution would work, I would not prefer it because it is counter-intuitive. What you are doing here is declaring in static configuration a log target that is not meaningful at all in a static context: you want to log to a UI control that has not been created, there is no good way to refer to it until the application's UI has been shown, and the UI will be shown at *some* point or (academically speaking) maybe not at all.

I believe it is preferable to create your own log target class deriving from `Target` or `TargetWithLayout`. You can pass any parameters necessary (e.g. the `ListView` instance) to the log target's constructor, and add the log target programmatically at the point where the values of these parameters become known (i.e. the UI is shown and we have a `ListView` we can refer to).

Comment: +1 a derived `Target` works pretty well in these types of scenarios.